# Example using geospatial indexing with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have been looking at using MongoDB instead of a custom geospatial database, however I am having difficulty at understanding how pymongo works with spherical coordinates.
Specifically I am not sure the $maxDistance (and similar have any effect).
For example if I execute this code:

```
db = pymongo.MongoClient().geo_example
db.places.create_index([("location", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])

cities = [{"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [57, 2]}, "name": "Aberdeen"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [52, 13]}, "name": "Berlin"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [44, 26]}, "name": "Bucharest"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [40, 14]}, "name": "Napoli"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [48, 2]}, "name": "Paris"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [35, -70]}, "name": "Tokyo"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [47, 8]}, "name": "Zurich"}]

try:
    result = db.places.insert_many(cities)
    for doc in db.places.find( {"location":{'$nearSphere':  [57, 2], "$maxDistance": 1}}).limit(3):
        pprint.pprint(doc)
except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print(bwe.details)
```

I would expect as answer just Aberdeen, instead I still get the 3 closest by even if the maximum distance is larger than 1 meter. I guess I am doing something wrong. 
Any help as well as better examples of pymongo usage (better than from the documentation) would really help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the older form of query where the distance is specified in radians. If you change to the [new format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) the `maxDistance` is specified in meters.

Also for reasons lost in the mists of time GeoSpatial data is sorted in Long/Lat order so all your coordinates need to be reversed. I've fixed your code up to use the correct coordinate orientation and put in the new query format. I also put in a `drop` command for the collection (as this is example code). This confused me and it may be confusing you. Multiple runs
of the program will insert the same points over and over. Without the drop
each query will return as many results as the number of times you have run the program. Finally I added a `GEOSPHERE` index which the documentation says you need even though your program runs fine without it. I suspect without this you will see a geometric decline in performance as the number of locations increases.

```
import pymongo
import pprint
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError

db = pymongo.MongoClient().geo_example
db.places.drop()
db.places.create_index([("location", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])

cities = [{"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [2, 57]}, "name": "Aberdeen"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [13, 52]}, "name": "Berlin"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [26, 44]}, "name": "Bucharest"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [14, 40]}, "name": "Napoli"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [2, 48]}, "name": "Paris"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-70, 35]}, "name": "Tokyo"},
          {"location": {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [8, 47]}, "name": "Zurich"}]

try:
    result = db.places.insert_many(cities)
    db.places.create_index([("location", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)])
    for doc in db.places.find({"location":{
                                "$nearSphere": {
                                     "$geometry": {
                                        "type": "Point",
                                        "coordinates": [2,57]
                                      },
                                     "$maxDistance": 1}}}):
        pprint.pprint(doc)
except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print(bwe.details)
```

Comment: Yes i know about the drop, I only copied part of the testing code. Normally I just do db.command('dropDatabase') to just drop everything. Anyhow, thanks a lot! I get my error and it is kind of confusing at times translating mongodb to pymongo!